# Laravel 4 security notice email from hosts regarding PHPSECLIB

Tags: laravel, phpseclib

I'm getting a security notice email from the hosts of my laravel site saying that

A recent security scan found files that are either

a.) suspect and should be checked to ensure their validity, or
b.) are part of a web application you installed but are out of date.

Warning - Feb 27 23:13:58 mojave
['/home/green/book/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/travis/setup-secure-shell.sh']
- Regular expression match = [\n(?!\s*(//|#|*)).*.ssh/]

Is this just a false positive from a over zealous security scanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False positive. It's probably "thinking" that the script is putting a backdoor on your system but it'd only do that if it were run. Of course, you'd have to run it first and the reason it's there is so that unit testing can be done. It's utilized by Travis CI to setup each instance whenever a commit or is made to phpseclib or to an open PR.

You can delete the whole travis directory if you like. It's not used for anything other than unit testing anyway.